# TypeError: Cannot read property <parameter> of null while passing data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, thus the question. This is my App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {loggedIn: false}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Helmet>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
                </Helmet>
                <Wrapper state={this.state.loggedIn}/>
            </div>

        )

    }
}

export default App;
```

I'm trying to pass the state to Wrapper component.

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const MainComp = this.state.loggedIn ? CoreLogged : CoreUnlogged;
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <Header state={this.state.loggedIn}/>
                    <MainComp />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default Wrapper;
```

I get the following error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loggedIn' of null
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: loggedIn is not a state in the Wrapper, its a property (i.e. use, this.props.state.loggedIn)

Answer (score 2):

in Wrapper component edit your **render** method to use **this.props.state** not **this.state** because you pass a prop named state to the component not in the instance and at the same time the state prop is a Boolean not and object edit your code to be something like this

```
 class Wrapper extends React.Component {

render() {
    const MainComp = this.props.state? CoreLogged : CoreUnlogged;
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <Header state={this.props.state}/>
                <MainComp />
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
  }
  export default Wrapper
```

if you're trying to make use of the state in the component you need to initialize the state in the constructor function

learn more here

[react state and life cycles](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

[component state FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html)

[understanding react.js state](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b)

Answer (score 1):

In your render method here

```
render() {
        const MainComp = this.state.loggedIn ? CoreLogged : CoreUnlogged;
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <Header state={this.state.loggedIn}/>
                    <MainComp />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
```

You need to change `this.state.loggedIn` to `this.props.state.loggedIn` since you are passing down via props to wrapper component.

I would also suggest not calling the prop state.